# executing if condition after a function called in else part. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am checking data if its not exist than insert. so i am using if else condition.
take a glance on code.

```
if($_POST['save_appointment']){
if(is_user_logged_in()){
            $user_appontment_sql = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."table where status=1 AND event_id=1 AND user_id=2";      
            $get_user_data_row = $wpdb->get_row($user_appontment_sql);  
            if(isset($get_user_data_row)){
                echo '<div class="saved_thing">'.__('You have already filled form for appointment for this date').'</div>';
            }
            else{
                $push_form_data=array();
                if($_POST['username']){
                    $user_data=array('username'=>$_POST['username'],'usernamelabel'=>$_POST['usernamelabel']);
                    $user_name=array('name_data'=>$user_data);
                    array_push($push_form_data,$user_name);
                }

                $form_data_all=json_encode($push_form_data);

            $done = add_appointment($_POST,$form_data_all);
            if($done==true)
                         {
                           echo '<div class="saved_thing">'.__('Mange tak. Du hører fra os snarest !').'</div>';
                            $user_status_mail = "select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."volunteer_app_setting where meta_key='admin_email' OR meta_key='email_send_status' OR meta_key='email_template_accept'";    
                            $get_appointment_send_mail = $wpdb->get_results($user_status_mail);
                            $event_metadata=unserialize($event_datas_count[0]->pstdata_value);

                            if($event_metadata['notification_mail']=='1')
                            {
                                require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))."/volunteer-appointment/mail/send_mail.php");
                                $selected_template=$event_meta_data['mail_temp_form_submission'];
                                $from=$get_appointment_send_mail[0]->meta_value;
                                $data=array('first_name'=>$_POST['username'],'send_to_admin'=>1,'event_date'=>get_post_meta($_POST['event_id'],'event-date',true),'event_name'=>get_the_title());
                                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                                $send_mail=mail_user($current_user->user_email,$selected_template,$from,$data);
                                if($send_mail){
                                            echo '<div class="saved_thing">'.__('E-mail notifikation afsendt til administrator').'</div>';
                                         }
                                         else{
                                             //echo "<script>alert('Mail not send');</script>";
                                         }

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        echo '<div class="saved_thing">'.__('Fejl!!!').'</div>';
                        }
            //}
            return;
            }
}
}
```

first we check the data, if its not exist than go to else part. 
its is going in if part all the time even data is not exists but saving data . In else part `add_appointment()` is the issue. this function is saving the data.

I debug
code is checking the condition and if data is not exist in database than go to else part, save data using the function `add_appointment()` and after executaion of the function again its going to else condition and showing message `You have already filled form for appointment for this date`

Comment: I'm not good at php, but wont `isset($get_user_data_row))` always return true, when you are declaring it right above? My Guess is that you have to check its content, which the other answers Also points out. PS. when testing the answers dont forget to purge eventual server cache

Comment: upon reading the other comments it seems that the code is triggered twice? In that case maybe check if you have any event listeners that submits the form again.

Comment: yes , just after saving data. that should not check if condition again after saving data. Its working fine on local

Comment: It seems that you have to look at the code for submitting the form then, and not the actual php. Something is calling the php function twice

Comment: I have added complete code. if($_POST['save_appointment']) is checking form submission.

Comment: Remove "return" statement and try.

Comment: removed return statement, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition to

from -> `if(isset($get_user_data_row))`

to -> `if(!empty($get_user_data_row))`

Comment: if we don't use function add_appointment() in else condition than its all woks. But we are using this function to save data.

Comment: Where do you placed that function?

Comment: I have replaced isset($get_user_data_row) to !empty($get_user_data_row). And i have echo in all conditions. its not going in else part , but saving data.

Comment: no. what i am trying to say is:-
data is saving in else part , but after saving data its again checking if condition and showing message "you have already applied..." .
this should not check if part again. Its working fine on local. but not on server.

Comment: Will you please add all page code here so i can understand what exactly you have done in your code? Are you doing this in which page?

Comment: Template or any other core page of wordpress or inside a plugin?

Comment: To debug you need to echo $get_user_data_row variable before if condition and exit(), for both the condition so you can get idea what exactly you are getting in result.

Comment: I have added exit() in else part, and its going in else part.

Comment: Remove "return" statement and try

Answer (score 0):

If no rows are found, it will return `0`

```php
if($get_user_data_row > 0) {
    // Some code here
} else {
    // Some functions here
}
```

Comment: no its not working. as i said its after saving data its again checking if condition after saving data, which is doing the function add_appointment() and its ib else part